# Is the domain $(-\infty,0) \cup (0, \infty) = (-\infty,\infty) \cap (x \ne 0) = \Bbb R\setminus \{0\}?$

Tags: functions, notation

Title. I'm making flash cards for mathematical notation and I want to verify that my usage is correct:
 
∪ (union): two non-overlapping domains but are treated as one (OR operation) 
∩ (intersection): two overlapping domains but must both be satisfied (AND operation)
ℝ - {`set`}: the set of all real numbers except for those included in {`set`}

Comment: Yes but you probably mean $x\neq 0$. Also, this notation is not standard. More commonly, instead of $(x\neq 0)$, we would write $\{x\in\Bbb R:x\neq 0\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why it would be $x\neq 3$, but assuming this is a typo.

Anyway, when you have $(-\infty,\infty)\cap $a set, you just are going to get the set itself again, so there's no point in writing the $(-\infty,\infty)$. Further, you should write $(x\neq 0)$ as a set using $\{,\}$: $$\{x:x\neq 0\}$$ or possibly $$\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x\neq 0\}$$

Comment: yeah, that was a mistake. Thanks for the reply :)